# Hive query issue :parameters

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to assign a 'select value' in a parameter and use it in hive code instead of assigning constant to a parameter.

In Hive, set a = 10; //but instead of this how can we assign dynamic values, as follows:

I Need: set a = select max(x) from y; //which assign maximum value of 'x' from table 'y' to 'a' parameter.

Ayesha

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use select instead of set, when you are assigning values  directly from queries.

```
SELECT @variable1 = column1, variable2 = column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = 'unique value'
```

or

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '<directory>' SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Used above method to incorporate '@var1=column1' but there is an error: 'ParseException line 1:7 character '@' not supported here' 

I am currently using Hive version 0.12, may be thats why i m facing such error. While this issue have now been resolved , in recent 0.13 exception.

Is there any other way to achieve above issue in 0.12 hive version

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this from within Hive, but you can kind of do it from outside Hive, like in a bash script:

```
a=`hive -S -e 'select max(x) from y'`
hive --hiveconf "a=$a" -e '[next query here]'
```

Comment: Can we not add : '${hiveconf:a}' to use the value assigned to 'a'.
I still didn't get ur next statement Joe, "hive --hiveconf "a=$a" -e '[next query here]'"

Comment: Yes, the next query would contain ${hiveconf:a} to use that value. For example, `hive --hiveconf "a=$a" -e 'select * from z where x = ${hiveconf:a}'`